# How to create an incrementing calculated field based on another field

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with these columns....

**ID, Location, ProductName, ProductCode**

Sample data....

```
ID, Location, ProductName, ProductCode
1, Miami, Gloves, 100
2, Tampa, Gloves, 203
3, Miami, Hats, 101
4, Tampa, Hats, 204
5, Miami, Balls, 102
6, Tampa, Balls, 205
```

As you can see, currently the same product may have different ProductCodes, depending on the location. Gloves uses both 100 (Miami) and 203 (Tampa).

My goal is to create a NewProductCode column. The NewProductCode will be the **SAME** for each product sharing the same ProductName, and will start at 500. So, taking the same list, this would be the result....

```
ID, Location, ProductName, ProductCode, NewProductCode
1, Miami, Gloves, 100, 500
2, Tampa, Gloves, 203, 500
3, Miami, Hats, 101, 501
4, Tampa, Hats, 204, 501
5, Miami, Balls, 102, 502
6, Tampa, Balls, 205,502
```

Since there are over 1000 records, I would prefer that NewProductCode be a CALCULATED field. So, basically, I could sort the list by ProductName first. Then, calculate the NewProductCodes, with similar products having the same code, then increment for the next, etc...

How can I do this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Will the table be sorted on Product Name so like names are together?

Comment: Yes, the table can be sorted however you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return the correct code even if the table is not sorted:

Put 500 in E2 and in E3 put this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:E2,MATCH(C3,$C$1:C2,0)),MAX($E$1:E2)+1)
```

It will try to find a match, if it does it returns the same value.  If no match is found it returns the max value + 1.

[image]

---

If it is always sorted on the ProductName then a simple IF can be used in lieu of the formula above:

```
=IF(C2<>C3,E2+1,E2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative as I like these puzzles :)

In E2 put:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH($C$2:C2,$C$2:C2,0),ROW($C$2:C2)-ROW($C$2)+1)>0))+499
```

And drag down.